# How to find if a number or fraction is integer in java?

Tags: java

How to find if a number or fraction is an integer in Java?

I did some research before but struggle to apply them. I want to do something like this:

```
if (x is int){
   //commands
}
```

Comment: What type is `x`?

Comment: what's the data type of x in your case?

Comment: How do you find if a number is an integer or a fraction without Java?

Comment: A fraction is an integer if its denominator divides the numerator: `num % den == 0`.

Comment: You're always guaranteed the type of a primitive.  It gets slightly murkier with `Number` since any primitive numeral can unbox to `Number`, but it largely depends on how you're getting the value in the first place.  Is it a primitive or an object?

Comment: x is a double..

Comment: I want x to be like 2.5 or 10/3

Comment: If a double is between -2^53 and 2^53-1, cast it to long and back to double, see if the value is the same as the original. Any finite value outside that range will always be an integer, because there is insufficient precision for it to be otherwise.

Comment: I did research on that, but didn't really work fo rme

Comment: Wait - do you want the mixed number variation of the double? That's...a display concern and absolutely has nothing to do with the actual storage of the number itself.  You'd have to do some custom display work to get that to work out.

Comment: Like a mix number it self can be a double, 10/4 == 2.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use something like this:

```
if((x%1)==0){
//do stuff
}
```

This checks to see if the decimal part of the number is zero.

Comment: how do you do the same with infinite digit decimal, like 10/3

Comment: when I do double c=10/3;
if(c%1==0){
System.out.print(c);

    }

Comment: It prints 3.000

Comment: @SkillHHY That's an issue with your division. `10/3` is integer division. Try `10.0/3.0`. Or only one (`10.0/3` or `10/3.0`) or cast (`((double)10)/3`). See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0

Comment: Thank you very much